# LyX - changing subsection from numbers to letters

Tags: sectioning, numbering, lyx

I have a problem set that I want to type up.

In my section, i get numbers which is fine since I have 4 problems on my problem set. But each subsection is lettered on my problem set, so I would like my solution set to also match it.

Right now it turns into 1.1, 1.2 ...

Also when I select subsection and try to do a display type formula, it moves my section number in the middle too. If I press enter on it it just removes the subsection. What to do? 
thanks

Comment: STILL havnt figured this out./

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't know whether LyX has any buttons for this type of thing, but for the first part of your question, you can add

```
\renewcommand\thesubsection{\thesection.\alph{subsection}}
```

to the preamble (under Document > Settings). If you have chapters, you should add `\thechapter.` before `\thesection`.

I don't understand your second question: When I add a display math under a subsection heading everything works fine (and it obviously fails to compile when I add it inside a subsection heading). I might be missing something though—I have never actually used LyX.